# file:write() error: "bad argument #1 to 'write' (string expected, got nil)"

Tags: lua

```lua
local log = io.open("log.txt","a")
local logText

for i=1,8 do --in case you claim this is pointless, it's here because it might affect the outcome and it has a use in other places of my program
  if a == 1 then --throwaway variable for this example
    press = 4; logText = "A = 1."
  else
    press = 8; logText = "No other rules apply."
  end

  if i == 8 then
    log:write(logText)
    log:write("\nCorrect combination: "..press.."\n") --claims error is here
    log:close()
  end
end
```

The second `log:write()` is throwing an error (`bad argument #1 to 'write' (string expected, got nil)`) claiming it doesn't have a string when I'm feeding it one directly in the function, and it's annoying me greatly. However, the error doesn't occur all of the time - other times, it works perfectly, for seemingly no reason. Secondly, when I put in an `if` statement above said `log:write()`, it now thinks the error is on the line with the `if` statement, e.g:

```lua
if press ~= 0 then --claims error is here
  log:write("\nCorrect combination: "..press.."\n")
end
```

I have multiple duplicates of this example of code among my program with different variables/values, and I've verified that they're all the same multiple times.

What possible error could this be throwing, and why?

Comment: Does your example reproduce the error? It seems that it does not. Best guess is that it's because `press` and `logText` might be `nil` in some cases (again - not reproducible in your example). Try `local logText = ""; local press = 0` in the beginning of the file.

Comment: Still gets the same error, sadly.

Comment: If required, I can send you the entire file.

Comment: Depending on the size of the file. I would prefer to have an example that reproduces the problem. If you can't do that, we could possible try to work it out with entire file.

Comment: The problem is that I'm not sure what's causing the problem. I don't know if the issue is the IDE (it's recently thrown an error about OLD code, see: https://imgur.com/a/jvXJMot) or the code itself.

Comment: The screenshot you have sent clearly states that `logResult` is `nil`. It's probably similar case to what was happening to `press` and `logText` in example attached here. Try adding `logResult = ""` (empty string; add local if needed).

Comment: Okay, it turns out my IDE hadn't saved any of my changes. Setting `press` to 0 and `logText` to a default value seems to have fixed most of it, though I now have a completely separate problem. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is not reproducible in the example from the question there is a possibility that with a script written in a similar manner both `press` and `logText` remain `nil`. That's because they are given their values only in selected branches of the program.

Try assigning them "empty" values beforehand to avoid `nil` issues with concatenation or `io.write`:

```lua
local log = io.open("log.txt","a")
local logText = ""
local press = 0

-- Rest of the logic.
```